# Assigning array of pointers to string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

I have tried searching on the web but found nothing like what I am trying to do. Hope you can help me out.

Problem: I have 2 char arrays, namely `string` and `string2`. Both are initially empty. I then give 2 inputs into these strings. I want to assign the value in string using pointers to string2.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    char string[2][MAXLEN];
    char string2[2][MAXLEN];
    char *pointer[2];
    pointer[0] = &string2[0];
    pointer[1] = &string2[1];
    scanf("%s", string[0]); //Assume i scan in "ab"
    scanf("%s", string[1]); //assume i scan in "cd"

    //Now string[0] contains "ab" and string[1] contains "cd"
    //I want to deferences the pointer and assign "cd" to it, so string2[0] will contain "cd"

    *pointer[0] = string[0];
    printf("%s", string2[0]); //but this does not print "cd"
}
```

*Edit
I understand i can use strcpy, but im trying to learn to do it using pointers. Any help in this regards would be great.

Comment: See [ask], and provide the required information. What is your question? Note: An array is not a pointer! Remove the address-of operator.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `strcpy` function?

Comment: You probably want `strcpy(string2[0], string[0]);`  instead of `*pointer[0] = string[0];`.

Comment: ... and you dont have 2 char arrays, but you have 2 arrays of char arrays.

Comment: The compiler told you that you are assigning a pointer to an integer, didn't it — in `*pointer[0] = string[0]`?  Heed your compiler warnings; they're pointing at bugs in your code.  `*pointer[0]` is a single character; `string[0]` is a pointer to an array.

Comment: Also read difference (syntax and semantics) between pointer to char, array of char pointers, pointer to char array.

Comment: Yeah. I could use strcpy. But im trying to learn to copy strings using pointers. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: You are going to have to copy of character of the string then individually until you reach the end of your array or until a '\0' character is found - which amazingly enough is what one of the strcpy functions does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not copying whole structures of info that the compiler can understand, you need to copy each element of the array individually.  Usually this is done with a for loop checking for NUL or size, but I am cheating and just showing you the syntax that would do the copy you want:

```
#define MAXLEN 10

int main(void) 
{
    char string[2][MAXLEN];
    char string2[2][MAXLEN];
    char *pointer[2];
    pointer[0] = &string2[0];
    pointer[1] = &string2[1];

    // Replace scanf for simplicity
    string[0][0] = 'a'; string[0][1] = 'b'; string[0][2] = '\0';
    string[1][0] = 'c'; string[1][1] = 'b'; string[1][2] = '\0';

    // For loop or strcpy/strncpy/etc. are better, but showing array method of copying
    pointer[0][0] = string[1][0];
    pointer[0][1] = string[1][1];
    pointer[0][2] = string[1][2];

    printf("%s", string2[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

For pointers, you could do this:

```
#define MAXLEN 10

int main(void) {
  char string[2][MAXLEN];
  char string2[2][MAXLEN];
  char *pointer[2];
  pointer[0] = &string2[0];
  pointer[1] = &string[1];  // changed this

  string[0][0] = 'a'; string[0][1] = 'b'; string[0][2] = '\0';
  string[1][0] = 'c'; string[1][1] = 'd'; string[1][2] = '\0';

  *pointer[0]++ = *pointer[1]++;
  *pointer[0]++ = *pointer[1]++;
  *pointer[0]++ = *pointer[1]++;

  printf("%s", string2[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

The pointer magic above turns into:

```
  char temp = *pointer[1];  // Read the char from dest.
  pointer[1]++;  // Increment the source pointer to the next char.
  *pointer[0] = temp;  // Store the read char.
  pointer[0]++;   // Increment the dest pointer to the next location.
```

and I do it 3 times - one for each char of input.  Surrounding that with a while() check against sourcePtr == '\0' basically turns it into strcpy().

One more fun example where a dereference might do what you expect:

```
typedef struct foo
{
    char mystring[16];
} FOO;

FOO a,b;

// This does a copy
a = b;

// This also does a copy
FOO *p1 = &a, *p2=&b;
*p1 = *p2;

// As does this
*p1 = a;

// But this does not and will not compile:
a.mystring = b.mystring;

// Because arrays in 'C' are treated different than other types.
// The above says: Take the address of b.mystring and assign it (illegally because the array's location in memory cannot be changed like this) to a.mystring.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can i just ask, what does
*pointer[0]++ = *pointer[1]++;
  *pointer[0]++ = *pointer[1]++;
  *pointer[0]++ = *pointer[1]++; 
do? Like how should i read it. 
My second question is that, do i have to change pointer[1] to &string[1]? Is there no way i can just do it by assigning it via string[1]? 
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that is a bit dense.  It's a common idiom in system programming.  I'll break it up in my answer for you a bit more.

Comment: Alright thanks man. I think my major question would be about if it is necessary to  assign pointer[1] to &string[1]. 
And is assigning it one by one like this the only way? So i cant do it by assigning the whole string? 
So taking a variable pointer as an example. char string = "Hello". char*pointer = string2. 
Deference pointer: *pointer = string.
This should assign string2 hello right? can i do the same for my case?

Comment: No - *pointer = string does not assign the whole string nor does it compile because you are telling it to put a pointer into a char.  That aside, it cannot work because, at compile time, it has no idea how big the actual string will be - and assigning the whole size of the array is something that 'C' doesn't do - probably for efficiency reasons.  Let me add one more example of a non-string copy that might make it clearer.